# Invoking Task UI in Siebel 8

Tags: siebel

I'm trying to invoke a Task UI in Siebel 8 and don't get anywhere.

I've added a button to an applet, with Method Invoked "LaunchTask" and
the following Control User Prop:
  Name: Task Name
  Value:

That button doesn't even show up in the UI. When I change the Method
Invoked to something else the button is displayed.

Does anybody have an idea why the button is not shown?

I've activated and deployed the task, and am running this on the
dedicated client against my local database.

I also tried invoking the Task from an applet server script, as
described in the bookshelf. That crashes the Siebel client.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I found the problem.

My responsibility didn't have access to the Task.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to invoke from Button, Method Invoked should be "TaskLaunch".
Please update the method invoked and try it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I stated in my own answer I did find the actual problem, long time ago.